# Websphere console is not opening

Tags: websphere, oms

Websphere console is not opening where my application is deployed .I am using PEN VPN to connect to the URL.It is giving "ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH".
URL: https://10.59.33.6:9043/ibm/console/logon.jsp
PFA screenshot.

Comment: What WebSphere version are you using? What browser? Have you tried different browser? Did you change any SSL settings in WebSphere? There is way too little info in your question for anyone to provide good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check the following document:

Access to Websphere admin console throws ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH after updating to Chrome v98 or later when Websphere is configured for SSL_TLS protocol

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/6561631